# compute cost of 2 dimension array in neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I am working to predict the position of the hurricane base on the history data of hurricanes in the pass. I use back propagate neural network for prediction.
The input data are 5 neural ([phi, distant]) and the output is 1 neural [phi, distant]. But I get a trouble when compute cost (output - target output).
Now I compute cost by change input from [phi, distant] to h(x) = a.phi + b.distant  but it seem not efficient (accuracy about 30%).

The data in [here](https://github.com/hamhochoi/Storm_prediction/blob/master/storm.xlsx), my code is [here](https://github.com/hamhochoi/Storm_prediction), all you need are read_storm_data.py, read_storm_xlsx_file.py and vector_storm.py/

So if anyone have a idea please help me, thank you a lot!

Comment: I would not code everything from scratch and use Keras https://keras.io/ . I think that the effort you put into implementation of NN backprogation and such things just distracts you from the real problem which is here the hurricane prediction.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. In fact, I use tensorflow to implement my code so it not too complicate, but the point is I don't know how to compute the cost to apply gradient descent on this cost. I use a function as above but it seem not good.